# How in nginx put in variable content of file?

Tags: nginx

How in nginx config put in variable content of plain file? For example I want to put in $ContentType content of file /opt/storage/articles/2013/07/29/file-3.content_type

Sory for my english

Answer (score 1):

To include information from other files within your nginx.conf you have to use *include* (ex):

```
include /opt/storage/articles/2013/07/29/file-3.content_type
```

Comment: yep, but include will add the information into config file, rather then putting it into a variable

Comment: now i've got you... afaik nginx variables can be only strings.